# Running django-dbbackup on heroku yields No such file or directory error

Tags: django, heroku

I'm trying to use django-dbbackup to backup to S3 from my django app running on Heroku. Locally, from the sqlite database, this works. On Heroku though, after running the command via heroku run:

`heroku run python manage.py dbbackup`,

there is an error:

`OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`.

After exploring the source code of django-dbbackup I figure it might be related to this line: `output_file = tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile(max_size=10 * 1024 * 1024)` where the dump is temporarily saved, so I assume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like pg_dump (which is used by this tool) is not available on heroku dynos. Still looking for a solution for this.